# Exit stauts 1 in golang

Tags: go

Got this simple function that throws and error with exit status 1 without any further hints to why this is happening

```
func execute_this(cmd string ) string {
    out, err := exec.Command("cmd","/C", cmd).Output()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
        fmt.Println(out)

    }
    fmt.Println(string(out))
    return string(out)
}

func main() {

        var cmd string 
        var result string 
        cmd = "pwd"
        
        

        result = execute_this(cmd)

        fmt.Println(result)
}
```

throw error message

```
2021/10/27 01:12:06 exit status 1
exit status 1
```

The goal is to write a function that executes system commands in shell and returning the output as a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, it will allow you to also see the output sent to the stderr. Details [here](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.17.2:src/os/exec/exec.go;l=100).

Specifically, in your case, the problem is that

```
'pwd' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os/exec"
    "os"
)

func execute_this(cmd string ) string {
    c := exec.Command("cmd","/C", cmd)
    c.Stderr = os.Stderr
    
    out, err := c.Output()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    return string(out)
}

func main() {
    cmd := "pwd"
        
    result := execute_this(cmd)
    fmt.Println(result)
}
```